# Selecting a specific column in a option box using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select, lookup

I'm using the following php code to create a select option box:

```
$TypeLU = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM LookupList");
while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($TypeLU)) { 
    $TypeOptions = $TypeOptions."<option>$Row[1] $Row[2]</option>";
}
```

In HTML it gets displayed as a list with 2 columns. If I select and item from the list the value would be the concat of both `$Row[1] and $Row[2]` which is fine for display purposes, but I want to be able to 'extract' for example only $Row[1] as being the **'bound'** value which I can then use as refrence.

So in pure Javascript I want to be able to get the value of just $Row[1] for example:

```
var x = document.getElementById("selectbox").value;
// So x must be only $Row[1] and not the concat of $Row[1] $Row[2]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 $TypeOptions = $TypeOptions."<option value='$Row[1]'>$Row[2]</option>";
```

You may also want to consider escaping the variables in case they contain any `<` or `"` or other special HTML characters. See [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Full example with escaping:

```
 $TypeLU = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM LookupList");
 while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($TypeLU))
 {
     $Row[1] = htmlspecialchars($Row[1]);
     $Row[2] = htmlspecialchars($Row[2]);
     $TypeOptions = $TypeOptions."<option value='$Row[1]'>$Row[2]</option>";
 }
```